# C# Mongodb: How to find in nested list of documents and select one field

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following models:

```
public class Car
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public IList<Driver> Drivers {get; set;}
}

public Driver 
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string IsActive {get; set;}
{
```

I want to find a car by `id` and select driver's `id` that is active. So

```
var carId = "123";
carCollection.Find(c=>c.Id == carId)
```

How to add selection for active driver's id?

PS. Only one active driver could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using mongo driver this can be done like below

```
  var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("Id", carId), 
  Query.EQ("Drivers.IsActive", 
  "true"));

  MongoCursor<Car> cursor = carCollection.FindAs<Car>(query);
  if (cursor.Count() > 0 && cursor.ToList()[0].Drivers != null)
  {
     // use the cursor.ToList()[0].Drivers 
   }
```